# How do I keep //end main and //end class on the same line

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I am running Java eclipse 4.3.1

```
${filecomment}

${package_declaration}

${typecomment}

${type_declaration}//end class

//end main

"package tester;


public class test {

    public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    //end main
}
//end class"
```

I would like the image to look like this I tried everything I went into the java code style and changed every combination of clean up, code templates, format, and organize imports

```
package tester;


public class test {

    public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your problem would be... don't use unnecessary comments!

I can think of several reasons why you would want to enforce this kind of comments in your code, but I fail to guess any good one.

Unnecessary comments distract the reader from the things that matter while carrying absolutely no information. Noise!

I can not imagine why you would want to point out that the last line of the class is... well, the end of the class; also, if you feel the need to expose clearly where your main method ends, I guess you do not have a comment issue, but a design issue.

My advice is to stick to clean code.

http://nilsnaegele.com/codeedge/cleancode.html

http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments

And get a copy of the Robert C. Martin book: "The Clean Coder".

Hope this helps, and helps you when you get back to your code after some time.